# Quero apagar uma linha tr específica quando clico em excluir

Tags: javascript, html5

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>
        Professores - CRUD (Create, Read, Update, Delete)
    </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/css.css">
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Professores</h1>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <form id="form">
                    <div><h3 id="CorModotexto1"></h3>
                        <label>Nome</label>
                        <input type="text" required="required" name="nome" id="nome">
                    </div>
                    <div><h3 id="CorModotexto2"></h3>
                        <label>Contato</label>
                        <input type="text" name="contato" id="contato">
                    </div>
                    <div><h3 id="CorModotexto3"></h3>
                        <label>Documento</label>
                        <input type="text" name="documento" id="documento">
                    </div>
                    <nav>
                        <input type="button" value="Gravar" id="botao" name="botao" class="button-27" role="button">
                        
                    </div>

                </form>
            </td>
            <td>
                <table class="list" id="lista">
                    <thead>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td id="nome1">Nome</td>
                            <td id="contato1">Contato</td>
                            <td id="documento1">Documento</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>    
                <input type="button" value="Limpar" id="limpar" name="limpar" class="button-26" role="button">       
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    
    <script src="js/classes.js"></script>
    <script src="js/script.js"></script>
</body>







class Disciplina{
    constructor(id, nome, horas){
        this.id = id;
        this.nome = nome;
        this.horas = horas;
        this.professores = [];
    }

    addProfessor( umProf ){
        this.professores.push(umProf);
    }
}

class Turma{
    constructor( nome, serie, curso ){
        this.nome =nome;
        this.serie = serie;
        this.curso = curso;
        this.alunos = [];
        this.professores = [];
    }

    addProfessor( umProf ){
        this.professores.push(umProf);
    }

    addAluno( umAluno ){
        this.alunos.push( umAluno );
    }
}

class Pessoa{
    constructor(id, nome, contato, documento){
        this.id = id;
        this.nome = nome;
        this.contato = contato;
        this.documento = documento;
    }
    saudacao(){
        return "Oi, meu nome Ã© " + this.nome;
    }
}

class Aluno extends Pessoa{ //Aluno herda de Pessoa
    constructor(id, nome, matricula, contato, documento ){
        super(id, nome, contato, documento);
        this.matricula = matricula;
        this.turma = null;
    }

    addTurma(turma){
        this.turma = turma;
        this.turma.addAluno( this );
    }
}

class Professor extends Pessoa{ //Professor herda de Pessoa
    constructor(id, nome, contato, documento ){
        super(id, nome, contato, documento);//chama construtor da superclasse
        this.efetivo = true;
    }

    setEfetivo( ehEfetivo ){
        if(ehEfetivo === true || ehEfetivo === false){
            this.efetivo = ehEfetivo;
        }else{
            console.log('Valor de efetivo precisa ser booleano');
        }
    }
}











var botao = document.getElementById("botao");
var limpar = document.getElementById("limpar");

var professores = [];
var linha = "";

function submeterForm(){

    var nome = document.getElementById("nome").value;
    var contato = document.getElementById("contato").value;
    var documento = document.getElementById("documento").value;
    var professor = new Professor(1, nome, contato,documento);

professores.push(professor);
gravarNavegador();
limparCampos();
adicionaLinha(professor);
console.log(professores);
}
botao.addEventListener("click", submeterForm);


function gravarNavegador(){
    var dados = JSON.stringify(professores);
    localStorage.setItem("professores", dados);

}



function limparCampos(){
    document.getElementById("form").reset();
}
limpar.addEventListener("click", limparCampos);

function adicionaLinha(professor){
    var tabela = document.getElementById("lista").getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0]
    var linha = document.createElement("tr");
    var campoNome = document.createElement("td");
    var campoContato = document.createElement("td");
    var campoDocumento = document.createElement("td");
    var campoAlterar = document.createElement("td");
    var campoExcluir = document.createElement("td");
    campoNome.innerHTML = professor.nome;
    campoContato.innerHTML = professor.contato;
    campoDocumento.innerHTML = professor.documento;


var btnAlterar = document.createElement("input");
var btnExcluir = document.createElement("input");
btnExcluir.setAttribute("type", "button");
btnAlterar.setAttribute("type", "button");
btnExcluir.setAttribute("value", "Excluir");
btnAlterar.setAttribute("value", "Alterar");



btnAlterar.addEventListener("click", alterar);
btnExcluir.addEventListener("click", excluir);
campoAlterar.appendChild(btnAlterar);
campoExcluir.appendChild(btnExcluir);


    linha.appendChild(campoNome);
    linha.appendChild(campoContato);
    linha.appendChild(campoDocumento);
    linha.appendChild(campoAlterar);
    linha.appendChild(campoExcluir);
    tabela.appendChild(linha);

}


function alterar(){
 

}

function excluir(){
    localStorage.removeItem('professores');
    var teste = JSON.stringify(professores)
    document.getElementById("lista").getElementsByTagName("tr")[1].innerHTML = "";
}


function mostrarTabela(){
    if (localStorage.hasOwnProperty("professores")){
        professores = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("professores"));
        professores.forEach(function(professor){
            adicionaLinha(professor);

        });
    }


}
mostrarTabela()
```

Answer (score 1):

Troque por:

```
document.getElementById("lista").getElementsByTagName("tr")[1].remove()
```